# Django OnetoOne Field not Populating

Tags: django, model, save

I have a model which is named `Client`. It's defined in models in part as the following:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I've run `makemigrations` and `migrations`, but when I create a new client object and try to save it from forms I get and `Integrity Error: NOT NULL constraint failed: intake_client.username_id`.

`username_id` is the field name Django automatically generates with the migration, but saving these forms results in this field containing a null value and is not being generated automatically as a dependency by Django. If I set primary key to true in the username, it works ok, but then I have problems deleting the objects because Django says the model does not have an `id` field (since it is now changed to `username_id`). Why is Django not generating and putting the dependency values in the `username_id` field automatically when the instance is saved?

Comment: How are you setting the `username` value when creating the `Client` object? Also you shouldn't call it `username` because it's a link to the `User` model, so you'd be better off calling it `user`

Comment: I'm not doing anything with that field. username_id was set by DJango and I thought Django automatically assigns a key.

Comment: if the model is yours, you'll need to figure out what values objects have when you create them, so you'll need to figure out how that field gets populated with a user.